# Customize TFS 2013 Task board

Tags: tfs, customization, scrum

I have TFS 2013 installed and my Projects use the **Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013** template.

I want to customize the Task Board (Tasks are shown per Product Backlog Item which are assigned to a Sprint).

I know how to change Work-Item-Limits, Colors, and so on. (All are processed by the ProcessConfiguration (XML file)), but I don't know how to change the values in the PBI-Header.

**What I want to have:
Show PBI-Effort, Remaining Work & Completed Work on the PBI Item in the Task Board View (on the left side)**

The default has the sum of Remaining Work, but I wasn't able to figure out how to customize this because there are just 3 TypeFields accessible (Team, Activity, RemainingWork). Does anyone know how to customize them?

Comment: I think the answer to this is: Not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question is somewhat older, and a new version of Team Foundation Server is released, it is possible now to customize the information that is displayed on the Backlog Items and Work Items on the scrum board.

When you have upgraded to TFS 2015, you can go the the scrum board, and in the right corner will be a settings icon with the option "cards". In this menu can you add any property of the backlog item or work item that you want.

Source: [Visual studio website](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/tfs2015-vs.aspx#ccards)

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible with the processconfig or power tools, unfortunately.

**Solution 1**

Create an extension for TFS (can be done in javascript) where you modify the task board after you wishes. Only disavanges i found, was that the documentation was not easy to find.

Guy here shows a way to do it.
https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/creating-basic-javascript-plugin

**Solution 2**

This guy, Tiago Pascoal, have already wrote a plugin/extension to do the most of the missing things in TFS. Showing PBI info on task board etc.

Download his package from here.
http://pascoal.net/task-board-enhancer/

If you uses TFS online, then there is a chrome plugin instead:
https://vsoenhancer.com